# Como pasar dos parametros con AJAX y recibirlos en el controlador?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

Como puedo pasar dos parámetros con ajax y recibirlos en el Controlador como parámetros

```
public IHttpActionResult GetComplementoMateriaId(int id, int IdUnidad)
```

**Actualización:**

Bueno, en realidad es un GET lo que quiero hacer, trabajo con paginas .html, entonces lo que hago es que a partir de una tabla jqGrid selecciono un elemento y paso el id de ese elemento por la url, y lo que estoy tratando de hacer es pasar dos variables por url o si se puede pasar desde AJAX parecido a lo que me mandaste, y recibirlos en el controlador algo como esto

```
[ResponseType(typeof(COMPLEMENTOMATERIA))]
public IHttpActionResult GetComplementoMateriaId(int id, int IdUnidad){
    try{
        List<COMPLEMENTOMATERIA> lstComplementoMateria = LGComplementoMateria.GetComplementoMateria();
        List<COMPLEMENTOMATERIA> ComplementoMateria = lstComplementoMateria.FindAll(x => x.IdMateria == id);
        List<COMPLEMENTOMATERIA> Complemento = ComplementoMateria.FindAll(x => x.IdUnidad == IdUnidad);

        if (ComplementoMateria == null){
                    return NotFound();
        }
   }
}
```

para así hacer una doble consulta y obtener una lista, pero necesito recibir dos parametros en el controlador para que pueda hacer esa búsqueda

Comment: Siento que estás iniciando con ASP.net MVC y bueno, aquí tienes un workshop que hice hace poco https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Con la poca información en la pregunta, aquí te va una respuesta:

Asumiendo que:

1. El siguiente **JavaScript** será llamado desde una página con **Razor** (.cshtml):
2. Existe un **Div** donde se colocará el resultado del envío.

Tenemos el siguiente código:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: '@Url.Action("GetComplementoMateriaId","NombreDeTuControlador")',
 data: {id:ValorDelID, IdUnidad:ValorDelIdUnidad},
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",     
 success: function (response) {
      $('#resultado').html('');
      $('#resultado').html(response);
});
```